# no match for 'operator>>' when using simple 'std::cin' operation

Tags: c++

The syntax error returned is:

> no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'const char[32]')

Source which is returning the syntax error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

int main ()
{   
    std::cin >> "Hello, please enter your name: ";

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried:

1. `using namespace std`
2. Obviously, as you can see, including `<istream>` and `<ostream>` separately, as well as along with different libraries
3. including `<iostream>` by itself with no other libraries operating

I'm still fairly new, so that's all I could think to try.

Can someone tell me what I am overlooking?

Comment: *I'm still fairly new, so that's all I could think to try.* Take a book in you hands, don't guess with trials.

Comment: Are you trying to write output or read input? It seems like you've split the difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read from a stream, you must provide a variable that will accept the value. Your problem is you've provided a string literal. That makes no sense. Where do you expect the data to be stored, and what type should it be?

Probably what you wanted is something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, please enter your name: ";
    std::string name;
    if (std::getline(std::cin, name)) {
        std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, had a brain fart, I genuinely don't know how I forgot cin and cout operate separately.

Comment: You don't need the `std::flush`. By default, `std::cin` and `std::cout` are `tie`'d together, so reading input will automatically flush pending output first.

Comment: Cheers, will edit that out for the sake of simplicity.